# .php files see Apache environment variables, .html files don't

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, lamp

Consider this environment:

```
$ cat .htaccess
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
SetEnv Foo Bar

$ cat test.php
<?php
echo "Hello: ";
echo $_SERVER['Foo'];
echo $_ENV['Foo'];
echo getenv('Foo');
?>

$ cat test.html
<?php
echo "Hello: ";
echo $_SERVER['Foo'];
echo $_ENV['Foo'];
echo getenv('Foo');
?>
```

This is the output of `test.php`:

```
Hello BarBarBar
```

This is the output of `test.html`:

```
Hello
```

Why might that be? How might I fix it?

Here is `phpinfo.php`:
http://pastebin.com/rgq7up61

Here is `phpinfo.html`:
http://pastebin.com/VUKFNZ36

If anyone knows where I can host a real webpage instead of just the HTML for one, please let me know and I'll move the content to there. Thanks.

Comment: That is kinda weird.  What happens if you put a `phpinfo();` in the .html file?  Do you see any differences from what you see in a .php file?  Are you sure your Apache configuration isn't adjusting the configuration with a `<files>` directive or anything?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem but could not : Output of test.html is same as test.php Hello: BarBar. And I start wondering why one bar is missing.

Comment: Thank, Zoredache. In fact I see many more environment variables for the `.html` files than for the `.php` files. However, the `Foo` variable is only available in the `.php` files. I don't see any difference in the configuration section, though.

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU: It is not unusual that one or two of the methods won't work. I is unusual that `.html` and `.php` files will show them differently, though.

Comment: I agree. But without being able to reproduce your problem, I won't be able to help a lot. Could you post full apache and php config (change or hide some values if needed). Would you have phpinfo and most softare/os versions?

Comment: Thanks, I put the HTML of the two `phpinfo()` outputs on Pastebin. If you know where I can paste the page, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

the difference is visible in the block:

```
Environment
```

there in the html-version all variables are set in the old global form:

```
$HTTP_HOST, $HTTP_USER_AGENT, etc.
```

and in the new form too:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], ...
```

in the php version they are set only in the new form. it seems like the html-version uses another php.ini.

also i see the variable

```
$_SERVER["ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME"]    ="/var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper"
```

maybe the html-file is parsed with the

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: Thank you. Due to the AddType declaration in .htaccess I think that both the .html and .php files should be using the same configuration files. I will ask the server admin, though. Thank you Rubo.